# What is best TypeConverter for Uri?

Tags: android, android-room

What is the best method of converting `android.net.Uri` that it can be used with `RoomDatabase`?

Comment: Maybe uri.toString()?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to store and retrieve `Uri` with Room is to persist it in the form of `String`. Moreover we already have the APIs to convert `Uri` to `String` and vice versa.

There are 2 ways:

1. You'll handle the conversion of `Uri` to `String` and then storing it and same for fetching.
2. Let Room do that for you using a `TypeConverter`.

It's completely your choice and the app requirements to choose the way. That said, here is the `TypeConverter` for `Uri` <-> `String`:

```
class UriConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String?): Uri? {
        return if (value == null) null else Uri.parse(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(uri: Uri?): String? {
        return uri?.toString()
    }
}
```